# What do UFW's audit log entries mean?

Tags: firewall, logging, ufw

I'm sometimes getting a lot of these AUDIT log entries in

```
...

[UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=176.58.105.134 DST=194.238.48.2 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32137 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=36231 DPT=123 LEN=56
[UFW ALLOW] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=176.58.105.134 DST=194.238.48.2 LEN=76 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32137 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=36231 DPT=123 LEN=56
[UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=192.168.192.254 DST=192.168.192.254 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54579 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59488 DPT=30002 WINDOW=32792 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
[UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.192.254 DST=192.168.192.254 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54579 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59488 DPT=30002 WINDOW=32792 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
[UFW AUDIT] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.192.254 DST=192.168.192.254 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4319 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59489 DPT=30002 WINDOW=32792 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

...
```

What is the meaning of this? When do they occur and why? Should and can I disable these specific entries? I do not wish to disable UFW logging, but I'm not sure whether these lines are useful at all.

Note that this does not actually occur in `/var/log/ufw.log`. It only occurs in `/var/log/syslog`. Why is this the case?

More info

- my logging is set to medium: `Logging: on (medium)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your logging to `low` to remove the `AUDIT` messages.

The purpose of AUDIT (from what I'm seeing) is related to the non-default/recommended logging - however, that's a guess, and I can't seem to find anything concrete with that.

Comment: Level of log is in the option menu.

Comment: @MUYBelgium options menu of what tool?

Answer (score 14):

That depend on the line. Usually, it is Field=value.

There is IN, OUT, the ingoing interface, or outgoing ( or both, for packet that are just relayed.

A few of them are:

- **TOS**, for Type of service,
- **DST** is destination ip,
- **SRC** is source ip
- **TTL** is time to live, a small counter decremented each time a packet is passed through another router (so if there is a loop, the package destroy itself once to 0)
- **DF** is "don't fragment" bit, asking to packet to not be fragmented when sent
- **PROTO** is the protocol (mostly TCP and UDP)
- **SPT** is the source port
- **DPT** is the destination port

etc.

You should take a look at TCP/UDP/IP documentation, where everything is explained in more detailed way that i could ever do.

Let's take the first one, that mean that 176.58.105.134 sent a UDP packet on port 123 for 194.238.48.2. That's for `ntp`. So i guess someone try to use your computer as a ntp server, likely by error.

For the other line, that's curious, that's traffic on loopback interface ( lo ), ie that's not going anywhere, it goes and comes from your computer.

I would check if something is listening on tcp port 30002 with `lsof` or `netstat`.

Comment: Thank you. Port 30002 is a mongodb arbiter running. I don't know anything about `ntp` though, should I be worried?

Comment: No. NTP is just to set time, you likely already used without knowing ( when you check "use network to sync time" in gnome, it use ntp ). It just sync time across a network. Maybe the ip was part of the global pool of ntp network ( http://www.pool.ntp.org/fr/ ), hence the request from someone on the internet ?

Answer (score 3):

On top of what has been said, it is also possible to infer what is going to be logged by inspecting **iptables** rules.
Specifically the matching rules that are being logged can be filtered like this `sudo iptables -L | grep -i "log"`:

```
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "
Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
Chain ufw-user-logging-output (1 references)
```

Those are for the most part default rules. Inspecting the output above reveals the `ufw-before-*` chains to generate [UFW AUDIT ..] logs.

I'm not a big expert on iptables and the UFW manual is not very helpful on this but as far as I can tell rules matching this chain sit in [/etc/ufw/before.rules](https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/tree/conf/before.rules).

For example the lines below are allowing loopback connections which might have triggered the last two example lines in your log (the ones starting with [UFW AUDIT] IN=lo)

```
# rules.before
# ....
# allow all on loopback
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
# ....
```

As for my part, I get a lot of logged [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) packets on port 5353:

```
Mar 17 21:02:21 pc kernel: [133419.183616] [UFW AUDIT] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=146 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=22456 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=126
```

Which I think are caused by the following in `rules.before`:

```
# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
```

One way to deactivate those are to do fire up the following:

```
sudo ufw deny 5353
```